# Clean rules in Salesforce Classic Developer edition

Tags: visualforce, community

i can not find "clean rules" 
According to the documentation is available but could not find

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/data_dot_com_clean_add_geocode_information_to_all_records.htm

[image]

Comment: They changed the name the Data Integration Rules (2 releases later!) https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_datadotcom.htm

Comment: thank you so much.